# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta_{m,g}^{-1}t^{m}\frac{w'(t)g(t)}{w(t)}dt=-m$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Let $g(t), w(t): \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ two real-valued, positive functions. They are two *density generators* in the sense that, the functions $p_g(t)$ and $p_w(t)$ defiend as:

$$
p_g(t) =  \delta_{m,g}^{-1}t^{m-1}g(t) \quad p_w(t) =  \delta_{m,w}^{-1}t^{m-1}w(t)
$$

are *probability density functions* and

$$
\delta_{m,g} \triangleq \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{m-1}g(t)dt, \quad\delta_{m,w} \triangleq \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{m-1}w(t)dt.
$$

Both $g(t)$ and $w(t)$ satisfy the following property:

$$ 
\frac{\delta_{m+1,g}}{\delta_{m,g}} = m, \quad \frac{\delta_{m+1,w}}{\delta_{m,w}} = m.
$$

Let $w'(t)$ be the first derivative of $w(t)$.

I have to prove that:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta_{m,g}^{-1}t^{m}\frac{w'(t)g(t)}{w(t)}dt = -m.
$$

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!